# linux cache usage

Tags: linux

My Centos box seems to be using lots of caching, most of the used memory is used for cache, how can I find out what the cache is for?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16439708   10469864    5969844          0     197936    9534176
-/+ buffers/cache:     737752   15701956
Swap:     16763816          0   16763816
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cache memory in Linux-based machines is often used to cache disk blocks into memory to prevent writing to the harddisk and speed up I/O operations. Also, a lot of free memory is cached and released when it is actually *required*.

When interpreting the output of `free`, you should look at the second row for the **actual memory usage**.

**The above numbers can be interpreted as:**

- 9534176 kilobytes cached memory
- 737752 actually used memory
- 15701956 actually free memory

For more information, take a look at http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_admin/buffer-cache.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at /proc/slabinfo or use the command slaptop to have a top-like interface to the cache objects.

Comment: The appropriate command is slabtop, not slaptop :)

Answer (score 0):

The cache is for speed up the disk I/O operations.

As Linus Torvalds once said, "free memory is bad memory".
Linux kernel uses unused (by system/applications) memory for cache, should a program require more memory, the system gets it from cache.